# Applying colored border with CSS to Asp.net application . What's wrong?

Tags: asp.net, css, border

I have a page structured like this

```
<div id = "part1" >
    <div id = "cat1" >
        <asp:Label cssClass="titles" runat="Server" />
    <-- more code ... -->
    </div>

    <div id = "cat2" >
         <asp:Label cssClass="titles" runat="Server" />
    <-- more code ... -->
    </div>

    <div id = "cat3" >
        <asp:Label cssClass="titles" runat="Server" />
     <-- more code ... -->
    </ div>

  <div id = part2" >
   <-- some code ... --> 
  </div>

  <div id = part3" >
  <-- some code ... --> 
  </div>
```

The corresponding CSS file is like this:

```
#cat1 , #cat2 , #cat3
{
 float:left;
 width:auto;
 padding:5px;
 border-width:3px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color:#800000;
} 

.titles  
{
 padding:5px;
 border-width:3px;
 border-style:solid;
 border-color: #800000 ;
```

}

My goal is to have 3 columns with colored border and for each column one title (asp.net labels) with colored border.

But all I get is three columns and no borders.
Moreover titles seems to don't stay in the "part1 div" (I don't know how to explain better,it's like paddings impact).

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: where are you closing your div (part1)? close it and check again.

Comment: I wrote bad the code. However. I can't answer here. But I solved. With IE it doesn't work. with firefox works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't seem to be getting the first problem - which broswers are you trying it on?

one problem seems to be you're setting cssClass="titles" instead of class="titles"

am guessing the "</ div>" is a misstype of "</div>" & that you also want to close #part1 before opening #part2 (?)

is it definitely loading the css file? could you try embedding it in the html to check?

Comment: `cssClass` is the correct attribute in the `asp:` namespace - it should all get processed by ASP.Net.

Comment: `</ div>` is actually valid. You can have whitespace there, and before the `>`, just not between the `<` and the `/`.